# Adding or deriving two columns from a single column

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyspark

Given a folowing dataframe:

-

```
+------------------+--------------------+
|Customer_ID|Project_ID|QUESTION_TYP|ANSWER|
+---------+----------+-------------+---------+
   1            1         2nd QUES      YES
   1            1          2nd QUES     YES
   1            2          2nd QUES      NO 
   1            2          2nd Ques.     Yes
```

How do I add 2 more columns in the above data frame

> Blockquote

such as col_1 has the count of Yes answers and col_2 as the count of No answers.

```
 -+------------------+--------------------++--------------------+
|Customer_ID|Project_ID|QUESTION_TYP|ANSWER|col_1|col_2
+---------+----------+-------------+---------+------+-------------
   1            1         2nd QUES      YES.    2     0
   1            2          2nd QUES     NO      0.    1
   1            2          2nd Ques.    Yes     1.    0
```

Please help. I have tried most of the solutions but I am getting a total of yes or no, But I want row-wise.please help

Comment: what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like window functions.  Assuming you want the count by `customer_id`:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when answer = 'YES' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by customer_id) as col_1,
       sum(case when answer = 'NO' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by customer_id) as col_2
from t;
```

Or, if you want the count over all the data, just replace `(partition by customer_id)` with `()`.

Note:  This puts the counts in *both* columns.  If you only want the count in the column that matches the answer on the row:

```
select t.*,
       (case when answer = 'YES'
             then sum(case when answer = 'YES' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by customer_id)
             else 0
        end) as col_1,
       (case when answer = 'NO'
             then sum(case when answer = 'NO' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by customer_id)
             else 0
        end) as col_2
from t;
```

However, I think having both counts makes sense.